# Laptop making alarm sound when started

Tags: hp-pavilion, post

I have an HP Pavillion 15t laptop, but it froze at POST and is making a siren sound, similar to one of a police car. What is causing the noise and preventing my laptop from starting?

Comment: Can you please describe what the beeping/siren is like? (1 short beep, 2 short and 2 long beeps, etc.)

Comment: @jitter It's just a continuous siren, no beeps.

Comment: There is no BIOS Code for 1 long beep, so I'm lost.

Comment: How long would you say the beep is? Does it last 1 or 2 seconds, like 3 to 5 seconds, or does it keep going until you turn off the laptop? Also, what BIOS manufacturer do you have?

Comment: @jitter It lasts until the laptop is turned off.

Comment: Perhaps the hard drive is failing and screaming.

Comment: @John it's coming from the speakers.

Comment: I've had it once at work on my HP desktop pc. A 2 tone siren. Powerled would flash white and red. Can happen if there's something with the graphics card not being seated properly. When I turned it off, cut power, then pressed power for 30 seconds (with no cord attached) and then plugged power back in, all worked again.

Comment: Some PC's have a similar "siren" when BIOS password is being changed (I imagine to alert IT staff). Had you trued to change the password, and now need to confirm by pressing the correct keys?

Comment: @DrMoishePippik No, I have a personal laptop. This happened when I booted my laptop in the morning. I didn't enter the bios in ANY way.

Comment: @54657, Sorry, I wasn't stating that only corporate PC's have that noise; I've encountered that annoying feature on home HP's, for example.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I didn't enter the bios before or during the siren sound..